# Enable-AzStorageStaticWebsite command in Azure RM PowerShell module

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm

I am trying to create an automated script to create and deploy static website to Azure Storage Blob.

However, I still have to use `Azure.Storage` module instead of `Az.Storage`. Is there an equivalent Cmdlet for `Enable-AzStorageStaticWebsite` in Azure RM?

[image]

Comment: Not that is identical. I think "New-AzureRmStorageContainer" then using "Lock-AzureRmStorageContainerImmutabilityPolicy" may be as close as you are going to get. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/?view=azurermps-6.13.0#storage Using the Azure API to create the resource is an option as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not an equivalent command in  `Azure.Storage`(GA) module nowadays, you could use `Enable-AzureStorageStaticWebsite` with [`Azure.Storage  4.4.1-preview`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.Storage/4.4.1-preview), but the `Az` module is a new powershell module **also for Azure Resource Manager**, may be you could have a try.

If you would like to run scripts developed for `AzureRM` using `Az`, use the `Enable/Disable-AzureRmAlias` cmdlets to add or remove aliases from AzureRM cmdlets to Az cmdlets.

For more details, refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly encourage using the Az module for this.  IN AzureRM, Static websites is a preview in Azure.Storage:  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.Storage/4.4.1-preview

Answer (score 1):

You can also call it yourself:

```bsh
#function to Enable static website for the Azure Storage account.
Function Enable-AzureRmStorageStaticWebsite(
    [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $Context,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $IndexDocument,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $ErrorDocument404Path
) {
    $sasToken = New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Context $Context `
        -Service Blob -ResourceType Service -Protocol HttpsOnly -Permission wla `
        -StartTime (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(4)
    $body = (@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<StorageServiceProperties>
<StaticWebsite>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <IndexDocument>{0}</IndexDocument>
    <ErrorDocument404Path>{1}</ErrorDocument404Path>
</StaticWebsite>
</StorageServiceProperties>
'@ -f $IndexDocument, $ErrorDocument404Path)
    $headers = @{"x-ms-version" = "2018-03-28"; "x-ms-date" = (Get-Date -Format R); "Content-Type" = "application/xml"; "Content-Length" = [string]$body.length }
    $apiUrl = ("{0}{1}&restype=service&comp=properties" -f $Context.BlobEndPoint, $sasToken)
    Write-Verbose ('Enable-AzureRmStorageStaticWebsite -IndexDocument {0} -ErrorDocument404Path {1}' -f $IndexDocument, $ErrorDocument404Path)
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Body $body    
}
```

Please assure you have installed module [Azure.Storage](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure.Storage) 
 supporting the storage api-version '2018-03-28' (I believe powershell-version: 4.4.1 or higher)